# How to detect flash player version by js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, flash

This function always return `"0"` in IE

```
function getFlashVersion(){
 var flash = 'None';
 // Count down from 10.
 for(var i = 10; i > 0; i--)
 {
   try{
    flash = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash."+String(i));
   }catch(e){
     //console.log(e);
   }
   if(flash != 'None')
    return flash.GetVariable("$version");

 }
 return 0;
}
```

but chrome return `11.8.r800`

how to detect flash player version in IE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you will have better luck using the [swfobject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) library. Using this library you can simply do the following to get the flash version across browsers:

```
// returns a JavaScript object
var playerVersion = swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion(); 
// access the major, minor and release version numbers via their respective properties
var majorVersion = playerVersion.major;
```

Comment: IE says " 'swfobject' is undefined "

Comment: Have you included the `swfobject.js` file in the link provided? This library defines the swfobject functionality...

Answer (score 4):

Here is what is used in one of my projects,

Works good also on IE

```
function getFlashVersion(){
  // ie
  try {
    try {
      // avoid fp6 minor version lookup issues
      // see: http://blog.deconcept.com/2006/01/11/getvariable-setvariable-crash-internet-explorer-flash-6/
      var axo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6');
      try { axo.AllowScriptAccess = 'always'; }
      catch(e) { return '6,0,0'; }
    } catch(e) {}
    return new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash').GetVariable('$version').replace(/\D+/g, ',').match(/^,?(.+),?$/)[1];
  // other browsers
  } catch(e) {
    try {
      if(navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"].enabledPlugin){
        return (navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash 2.0"] || navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"]).description.replace(/\D+/g, ",").match(/^,?(.+),?$/)[1];
      }
    } catch(e) {}
  }
  return '0,0,0';
}

var version = getFlashVersion().split(',').shift();
if(version < 10){
  alert("Lower than 10");
}else{
  alert("10 or higher");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    var a, b, c, y ='length',v = "name",t = "indexOf",m = "match";
    if (c=window.navigator.plugins)
        for (var d = 0; d < c[y] && !b; d++) {
            var e = c[d]; - 1 < e[v][t]("Shockwave Flash") && (b = e.description) 
        }
    if (!b) try {
        a = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.7"), b = a.GetVariable("$version")
    } catch (g) {}
    if (!b) try {
        a = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.6"), b = "WIN 6,0,21,0", a.AllowScriptAccess = "always", b = a.GetVariable("$version")
    } catch (ca) {}
    if (!b) try {
        a = new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash"), b = a.GetVariable("$version")
    } catch (l) {}
    b &&
        (a = b[m](/[\d]+/g)) && 3 <= a[y] && (b = a[0] + "." + a[1] + " r" + a[2]);
    console.log(b) || void 0
```